# Meteor Cordova/Phone gap public assets path

Tags: cordova, meteor

I cant seem to get images or videos to resolve in my cordova meteor app, web works fine using an  example of /images/123.png

Is there a specific path or is it that the public folder doesn't get included in builds

Thanks